# any former recommendation for making background image in flutter app compatible with all screens?

Tags: image, flutter, dart, background, pixel

**Flutter dart**

I'm about to finish programming an application and I want us to set wallpapers for the application's pages as background .. and i need your help friends if there any recommendation to make image  Compatible with all screens for iOS and android

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Making images as a background for every page might make your application laggy and bulky. I would rather suggest you use inbuilt options like the simple background color.

If you want to use images only then you can have different resolutions of the image as asset and using `MediaQuery` and `LayoutBuilder` you can change the image as per the size of the device.

You can have a look at this [page](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/building-adaptive-apps) to know more about adaptive applications